Oracle Apex how to dynamically set inital postion and zoom of map
I have page on Oracle Apex (let's call it Page 1) that contains objects with their respectable attributes (IDs, names and GPS coordinates) as interactive grid. I want when somebody clicks the link of the object that links sends them to Page 2 initial position of map is above the object.
I assigned map initial position and zoom using sql query to coordinates of the object. However when I open map the map instead of being centered on object is centered on coordinated 0,0 meaning that initial position and zoom I set is being ignored by Apex
